# run git commands in program

Tags: git, github, ide, visual-studio-2005

We developed an ide we want to implement some git functions in this ide. like in visual studio.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/06/set-up-connect-and-publish-using-visual-studio-with-git.aspx

I try to use gitlib2 but it has some problems in windows. How can I run commands in git? is there any examples in c, CPP?

Thanks

Comment: Interestingly, the example you point to is written entirely against libgit2, so I'm not sure what these "problems in windows" are that you're referring to.  Could you expand on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We developed an ide we want to implement some git functions in this ide. like in visual studio.

Visual studio relies on **[LibGit2Sharp](http://libgit2sharp.com)**, a .Net binding to libgit2 to interact with local and remote git repositories. More on the underlying architecture in **[Martin Woddward's talk at TechEd 2013](http://dev9.channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DEV-B330)**.

Of course, depending on the language your IDE is built with you may choose to pick another binding (ruby: **[Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged)**, python: **[Pygit2](http://www.pygit2.org/)**, ...). You can find more information about existing bindings on the **[libgit2 project page](http://libgit2.github.com/)**.

> is there any examples in c, CPP?

If you're looking for some libgit2 sample usage, this **[StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780587)** may help you.

> I try to use libgit2 but it has some problems in windows.

The libgit2 team is always on the lookout to fix those kind of issues. Indeed, one of the libgit2 moto is to be *"100% cross-platform"*. Please let them know about your issues by creating some entries in the **[issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues)**